# Macro code to click on OK button in an Input Box that is launched through QTP

Tags: excel, vba, qtp

I am executing few QTP scripts through excel macro. But sometimes QTP throws some pop up where we have to click on OK manually after entering some value. I want to simulate this action in my macro code.

Below is the screenshot of Input Box that I want to handle:

[image]

Problem is that this **Input Box is launched through QTP Script** But I want to click on OK button using excel macro code. So, How can I get this Input Box and perform desired action?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: For the Input Box handling scenario, I don't know how to start.Rest all code works fine. I tried to find out on google but didn't get anything that could help me. I tried using "Application.DisplayAlert" but it didn't work for me.

Comment: can you attach a screen shot of the _input box_ in question?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. @Motti

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the QTP script is explicitly asking for user input during the test run. This means that you lose a lot of the advantages of *automation* by forcing a human being to sit next to the machine while the test is run.

I would suggest modifying the test so that it uses data automatically. In QTP this can be done via the [data table](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_datatables.htm) or via test (or action) [parameters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_actions.htm).

Comment: Thanks Motti! I agree with you but this only happens when I run the test set first time. However, I can modify the script but it's a part of already defined framework and I would not get the permission to modify the script. Is it not possible to do so via excel macro??

Comment: Sorry @RajKamal, I don't know